# What is this dystopia with only three channels on TV?

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

It's possible that I invented this and it doesn't really exist.

What I remember: one character is proudly showing off facets of their dystopia. They say that they've successfully reduced the number of TV channels to [some small number] and the goal is to soon reduce it to three, with an ultimate goal of only one.

I thought it was Nineteen Eighty-four, but my Google-foo has been inadequate to locate the scene. Other prime candidates are the major dystopias: Fahrenheit 451 and Brave New World. I most likely encountered it (if I didn't invent it in a dream) in a book during my school days, a little over a decade ago.

Comment: Until the 1980s, most of the UK only had three channels

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. - Was this a TV show, a novel, a movie? Who was the character and who were they showing off to?

Comment: This sounds very strongly like 1984 - *"The Eleventh Edition is the definitive edition,' he said. 'We're getting the language into its final shape—the shape it's going to have when nobody speaks anything else. When we've finished with it, people like you will have to learn it all over again. You think, I dare say, that our chief job is inventing new words. But not a bit of it! We're destroying words—scores of them, hundreds of them, every day. We're cutting the language down to the bone. The Eleventh Edition won't contain a single word that will become obsolete before the year 2050"*

Comment: @Valorum whoops, forgot to mention that it's almost certainly a book.  Aside from that, you have a much info as I recall.

Comment: @Valorum Similar for Germany. There were three publicly operated channels. The first is a joint channel by the regional public radio broadcasters, which to this day calls itself "Das Erste", "The First (program)". The second was started in the 60s and is still called ZDF - "Zweites Deutsches Fernsehen", "Second German TV". And then there was one regional channel for each area, operated by the aforementioned radio broadcasters. Those were collectively called "Die Dritten", "The Thirds". Only in 1981 the highest German court ruled that private channels were legal, and 1984 the first one started.

Comment: What medium? Novel/short story?  Comic?  TV/ Movie?  Also, when did you see it? Last year? 30 years ago?  I'll take a guess, it sounds like something out of Max Headroom.  The series was set in a near-future dystopia where there were thousands of TV channels. Literally anyone could broadcast a TV channel from their  basement. The quoted line sounds like a joke, the point being that British TV only had four channels at the time.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Headroom_(TV_series)

Comment: @Pete "I most likely encountered it (if I didn't invent it in a dream) in a book during my school days, a little over a decade ago."

Comment: Australia in the 1970s?

Comment: The past a generation or two ago.